# How create editable field more then 255 characters in Word-VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying create editable field in Word document:

```
Dim bm As Bookmark

If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists(g_name) = True Then
    Set bm = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(g_name)
End If

If g_var = "DETAILS" Then
    bm.Range.Select
    With Selection
     .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineNone
     .FormFields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:= _
         wdFieldFormTextInput
         Selection.PreviousField.Select
         With Selection.FormFields(1)
         .Name = g_name
         .EntryMacro = ""
         .ExitMacro = ""
         .Enabled = True
         .OwnHelp = False
         .HelpText = ""
         .OwnStatus = False
         .StatusText = ""
         With .TextInput
             .EditType Type:=wdRegularText, Default:=g_value, Format:=""
         End With
      End With
  End With
End If

ActiveDocument.Protect Password:="mypass", NoReset:=False, Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields
```

g_name contain the name of bookmark where some text had to be inserted,

g_value contain the text that had to be inserted in bookmark g_name.

This code is working, but only if g_value length less then 255 characters. If g_value length more then 255 the macros return error "String too long".

I've tryed insert text like this:

```
bm.Range.Select
With Selection
    .Text = g_value
    .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineNone
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
End With
```

And this work, but text field are non-editable.

How resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just use text form

[word_dev_tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qjy0.jpg)

And fill this form

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(g_name).Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = g_value
```